# PHP regex: Converting and manipulating text into specific HTML

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text:

```
I'm a link - http://google.com
```

I need to convert this into the following HTML

```
<a href="http://google.com">I'm a link</a>
```

How can I achieve this in PHP? I'm assuming this needs some sort of regex to search for the actual text and link then manipulate the text into the HTML but I wouldn't know where to start, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every time you get a `-` separeting the text from the link ?

Comment: Well, start by looking at one of the millions of examples out there on google.

Comment: @1nflktd There will only ever be one `-` in the text part, it's just to distinguish the actual text from the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its always like this, you don't really need regex here:

```
$input = "I'm a link - http://google.com";

list($text, $link) = explode(" - ", $input);

echo "<a href='". $link ."'>". $text ."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If a regex is needed, here's a fully function code:

```
<?php

$content = <<<EOT
test
http://google.com
test
EOT;
$content = preg_replace(
    '/(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/',
    '<a href=\'$0\'>I\'m a link</a>',
    $content
);
echo $content;

?>
```

Example here: http://phpfiddle.io/fiddle/1166866001

If it's always one line of text though, it would be better to go with 1nflktd solution.

Comment: Even if a regex is needed, why make it so complicated?  `/^(.*) - (.*)$/`

Comment: If the situation were always that simple, a regex wouldn't be needed in the first place. Which is why I said "If a regex is needed..."

Comment: See the comments on the question, it is that simple

Comment: It doesn't seem definitive. I only see Tom mentioning the one dash. I also didn't post this just for one person.

Answer (score 0):

Try with capturing groups and substitution:

```
^([^-]*) - (.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eA2dW9/1)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/^([^-]*) - (.*)$/i";
$str = "I'm a link - http://google.com";
$subst = '<a href="$2"">$1</a>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://google.com"">I'm a link</a>
```

---

Pattern Explanation:

```
^                        the beginning of the string

  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^-]*                    any character except: '-' (0 or more times)
  )                        end of \1
   -                       ' - '
  (                        group and capture to \2:
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times)
  )                        end of \2

$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```